# Sorting and outputting a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multi-dimensional array right now that looks like this:

```
function art_appreciation_feeds() {
 $items = array(
  array('site' => '', 'uri' => '', 'feed' => ''),
  array('site' => '', 'uri' => '', 'feed' => ''),
  array('site' => '', 'uri' => '', 'feed' => ''),
  array('site' => '', 'uri' => '', 'feed' => ''),
 );
 return $items; 
}
```

Right, so I output the values of the array using this function:

```
foreach($items as $i => $row) {
```

What I'm looking to do, is add another value to that array called `category` so that I'd have:

```
array(
  array('site' => '', 'uri' => '', 'feed' => '', 'category' => ''),
);
```

And when I'm going through the loop above, to output it in order by the `category` field with a `<h2>Category</h2>` at the top only of each section.

Is that the best way to do this and if so, how would I change my loop to accommodate that?  Caveat: I can change the array as well if you think something else is better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure there are better ways to go about it and not sure if this is easy to do in your situation, but just a suggestion. Why not have the category as an array key and inserting all the records relevant to that category as sub array?

for instance:

```
$items['catname1'][] = array('site' => '', 'uri' => '', 'feed' => '');
$items['catname2'][] = array('site' => '', 'uri' => '', 'feed' => '');
$items['catname1'][] = array('site' => '', 'uri' => '', 'feed' => '');
```

and then sorting based on the array key?

Or if you dont want to add that extra layer. Add a counter value to catname and store the catname in the sub array itself like

```
$items['catname1'.$c] = array('site' => '', 'uri' => '', 'feed' => '', cat=>'catname1');
$items['catname2'.$c] = array('site' => '', 'uri' => '', 'feed' => '', cat=>'catname2');
$items['catname1'.$c] = array('site' => '', 'uri' => '', 'feed' => '', cat=>'catname1');
```

using `ksort()` you should be able to sort on the array key easily.

Answer (score 0):

One way is using `usort()`, which allows you to specify a sort function:

```
function compareTwoItems($a, $b)
{
   return strcmp($a["category"], $b["category"]);
}

usort($items, "compareTwoItems");
```

Once `usort()` is done, the items are sorted, with all items of the same category being adjacent in the array.

If you want, you can continue to fine-tune your `compareTwoItems()` function -- e.g. do sub-sorting within a category:

```
function compareTwoItems($a, $b)
{
    $strcmp = strcmp($a["category"], $b["category"]);
    if ($strcmp != 0)
        return $strcmp;
    else
        return strcmp($a["site"], $b["site"]);
}
```

Comment: Not that I'm the downvoter (it's a valid solution IMHO), but **DO** quote your array_keys! (Or I'm gonna drive-by-define `define('category','site');` just to spite the code :P )

Comment: Okay, I quoted the array keys.

Answer (score 0):

Use **array_multisort** to sort multiple or multi-dimensional arrays.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Suppose, you have the following multi-dimensional array:-

```
array(
  array('site' => 'some value', 'uri' => 'some value', 'feed' => 'some value', 'category' => 'some value'),
  array('site' => 'some value', 'uri' => 'some value', 'feed' => 'some value', 'category' => 'some value'),
  array('site' => 'some value', 'uri' => 'some value', 'feed' => 'some value', 'category' => 'some value'),
  array('site' => 'some value', 'uri' => 'some value', 'feed' => 'some value', 'category' => 'some value'),
);
```

Suppose, the above array is stored in variable named **$data**

```
// Obtain a list of columns
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $category[$key]  = $row['category'];
}

// Sort the data with category descending
// Add $data as the last parameter, to sort by the common key
array_multisort($category, SORT_DESC, $data);
```

Hope this helps.